# Does Yahoo "deactivate" or "delete" accounts after 12 months of inactivity?

Tags: yahoo-mail, yahoo, yahoo-account

Does Yahoo **delete** email accounts due to inactivity?

Yahoo deactivates email accounts and deletes email contents if the owner fails to sign in at least once in a year. But it does not delete the account itself. I confirmed this by logging in to my ancient Yahoo account, found that all contents were gone, but the account ***did*** exist (which is why I was able to log in with the username and password).

[This](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/account/reasons-yahoo-deactivates-deletes-account-sln2018.html) page mentions the following:

> "Reasons Yahoo deactivates or deletes an account:-
>
> Depending on your account's history, it's possible for it to be
> removed from Yahoo and become inaccessible. You can always sign up for
> a new Yahoo Account, but keep in mind that your old Yahoo ID won't be
> available for you to use. These actions can result in an account being
> deleted:
>
> You requested that your account be deleted.
>
> **You haven't signed into your account within the last 12 months.**
>
> Your account was used in a way that violates our Terms of Service."

So not signing in for 12 months can result in an account being deactivated? Or deleted? Which one? Deactivation does not mean deletion, but just the contents get deleted (not the account) and the mailbox is considered inactive (not permanently closed).

What is the case here regarding 12 months of inactivity? Deactivation or deletion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mailbox gets de-activated - by that, all emails in your mailbox are deleted. The next time you login, the de-activated mailbox is re-activated and you start from scratch. Deletion implies that your account is wiped out and you need to re-register. However, that is not the case

Comment: Hi Sathyajith, I found the answer. It is not possible to remove all recovery methods. Thanks!